# is there a way to escape angle brackets ('greather than' or 'less than' symbols) in html comments?

Tags: escaping, comments, script-tag, html

Is there any way to escape the angle brackets (or even the entire script tags) inside this html comment block?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="20140330_v100.js"/> 

<!-- 
    The above can also be written with a closing script tag as:

        <script type="text/javascript" src="20140330_v100.js" ></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="20140330_v100.css" ></script>

    but I think the earlier form is the better one for XHTML
-->
```

Comment: What square brackets?

Comment: @TheBlueDog You're right -- there are none! I meant angle brackets. Updated the post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: &lt &gt are substitutions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the pointer -- I'll check that article out.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here should be fine without any further escaping.  The only thing you need to escape inside of an HTML comment is an end-comment sequence, --.  If the block you're commenting out already contains comments, you need to go in and remove or modify all the existing double-dash sequences.

Comment: Interesting. But unfortunately, the browser (Chrome) is reading it as a comment only up to the end of the second </script> tag.

Comment: @user1883050, what version of Chrome might that be? And please show a complete document where such a problem appears, and specify how you inferred what Chrome does.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I've updated the post to add 2 lines of offending code before the comment block. These 2 didn't have regular closing script tags, and I think that was causing the problem. I thought the "/>" would have obviated the need for the regular closing script tag... apparently I was wrong.

Comment: So this is about a “self-closing” `script` element, not about `<` and `>` in comment content.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Possibly so, I'm not really sure though!